# TinyMCE 4 - remove() or destroy()

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using [TinyMCE editor.](http://www.tinymce.com/) 
I want to remove or destroy tinymce editors (Page contain more then one editor). Also remove classes and IDs added by tinyMCE.

**But leave editable contents**

I tried :

```
tinymce.remove()
tinymce.destroy()
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'.editable');
```

**Please note:**

my editor class is `.editable`, And I have more then one editors in my page.

Comment: tinymce.remove() function is worked for me when editor call need for textarea in popup.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need an editor id (which usually equals your editor html root elements id (in most cases a textarea)).

Example:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'my_original_textarea_id');
```

Comment: I am able to remove all editor using `tinyMCE.remove()` but how to add it again ?? . You code was working too. the purpose of doing this is: My editable div is loaded using ajax, so when its load then I need to rebind the TinyMce to that div

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is the right way to do it: tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'my_original_textarea_id');

Comment: i've stumbled upon the same problem with 4.2 and the same situation only tinyMCE.remove(); then tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, '#IDNAME'); and Finally initialize the tinymce editor as $("#ProductDescription").tinymce({OPTIONS}) Fixed the problem

Answer (score 57):

I had the same problem. In v4 all suggestions above did not work for me, but this did:

```
tinymce.remove("div.editable");

... regenerated HTML dynamicaly ...

tinymce.init(...);
```

I use inline editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "div.editable",
    inline: true,
    plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"});
```

Hope this helped

Comment: This does not always seem to work to actually remove all said editors. Sometimes it just errors out, sometimes it only sporadically removes them.

Comment: This worked for me to remove the editors, but when I re-add the editors, they are uneditable.

`tinyMCE.remove('textarea');`

I don't have unique ID's for textareas, they are generated dynamically, hence I have a unique editor-selector class to identify tinymce editors.

How do I make the editors editable after removing and re-adding them?

Comment: Link to the documentation (with examples): https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#remove

Answer (score 31):

Just in case anybody arrived here who is using the jQuery version of TinyMce use the following instead to remove **an instance**:

```
$("#textarea_id").tinymce().remove();
```

Comment: This will only remove the first instance of the editor. If you need all instances matching the selector removed, then you need to do like this: `$(".editable").each(function() { $(this).tinymce().remove();});`

Comment: I did write above "an instance", hence a single instance of the tinymce. Of course, there's various ways of iterating through multiple instances and removing them. Niels is one such method.

Comment: I found this worked for me: tinymce.get('textarea_id').remove();

Comment: now code is diferent:  tinymce.remove('.class_objects'); or  tinymce.remove('#id_object');

Answer (score 19):

The following code is working

```
tinymce.get(id).remove();
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply use

```
tinymce.remove()
```

to remove all editors.

Comment: You did not even read the question.  That is the first thing OP tried.

Answer (score 6):

Bear in mind that if given `textarea` has an id, tinyMCE will use it for some strange reason, even if `selector` parameter has been used to apply editor to given element. This id is then used in internal array - `tinyMCE.editors` which isn't cleared (isn't cleared if you'll use `tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, [id])`, `remove` actually removes `editors` and prevents tinyMCE to be applied ever again). As such if you have a dynamic content with tinyMCE applied, it will work once, but never again. To resolve this you need to clean this array manually per `delete tinyMCE.editors[$(node).getAttribute('id')]`

Answer (score 4):

You need simply use this code in order to remove all the editable textarea:

tinyMCE.remove(".editable");

Here more info about tinyMCE remove:
http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.EditorManager.remove.static

Comment: `tinyMCE.remove(".editable")` doesn't remove the editor for me. I actually have to use `tinyMCE.get(".editable").remove()` to remove the editor from the internal array.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple Instances of TinyMCE you can use following code snippet to close every instance of TinyMCE:

```
for (var i = tinymce.editors.length - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--) {
    var ed_id = tinymce.editors[i].id;
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveEditor", true, ed_id);
}
```

I use it before the Ajax Content is loaded.

Comment: VERY important to note that this cycle goes backward. If it had started from 0 to length, it would result in random, unexplainable errors!

Answer (score 3):

tinymce.EditorManager.remove()
This was working for me

Comment: `tinymce.EditorManager.remove('.editable')` worked for me.

Comment: this one also works on my setup, appreciate your code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party but I recently added tinyMCE jQuery version to my angular project. For a few reasons I did not want to use the angular 3rd party code and just wanted the jQuery version to work.

So here is my code for making TinyMCE 4.x work in angular, even with ng-repeat.

All you have to do is decorate your textareas with the class "TinyMCEEditorBox" and call this method anytime you remove or add items that result in an update (such as more items being added to an ng-repeat).

```
$scope.RebindTinyMCE = function ()
{
    var tmceSelector = ".TinyMCEEditorBox";

    for (var i = tinymce.editors.length - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--)
    {
        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveEditor", true, tinymce.editors[i].id);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(tmceSelector).tinymce({
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: false,
            toolbar: 'bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link',
        });
    }, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fake a virgin website

TinyMCE will check if its already loaded in `window.scripts`. If you remove the according entry TinyMCE will behave like it is a untouched document.

```
function cleanTinyMCE() {
  for (var i=0; i < window.scripts.length; i++) {
    if (window.scripts[i].match('.*tinymce.*js.*')){
      delete window.scripts[i];
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By simply using this you can remove *TinyMCE* editor:

```
tinymce.remove('#your_textarea_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `tiyMCE.init({}) fuction`, the answer by @nikmauro works for me, so for every unload of the page, you just trigger the `tinymce.get("real_element_id").remove();`

That method works for me.

BTW, I amusing this version

```
//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

we were getting error on calling
`elementReference.destroy()`  // destroy is a dojo function
we replaced that code with
`elementReference.domNode.remove()`
we were also using tinymce.min.js, and it was giving us NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof tinyMCE != 'undefined') {
    if (tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() != false) {
        tinyMCE.editors=[]; 
    }
    tinyMCE.editors=[]; tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',  plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview'});
}else{
    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',  plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get or fine a reference to your editorID then:
tinyMCE.get(editorID).remove();

I use this where there are many TinyMCE instances running on a single page and it would cause significant issues if they were not removed properly.