# Getting 'NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED' while using tinymce in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, firefox, tinymce

I am using tinymce in my application for a rich text box experience, I am getting this weird problem while using it in Mozilla.
It works perfectly while using it first time, but if i load same tinymce instance second time it is giving below error in console screen.

**NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED**

Please suggest the solution if any , Below is the code I am using:

```
 <script type="javascript">
    tinymce.remove();
    jQuery('#tinymce').tinymce({
        height: 250,
        width: 750,
        entity_encoding: "raw",
        encoding: "xml",
        force_br_newlines: false,
        force_p_newlines: false,
        forced_root_block: 'div',
        statusbar: false,
        theme: 'modern',
        menubar: false,
        plugins: "mention " + plugins,
        toolbar1: toolbar1,
        toolbar2: toolbar2
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

To get rid of this problem simply wrap `tinymce.remove()` in try catch.

```
    try {
        tinymce.remove("#id");
    } catch (e) {}
```

The cause of this problem is that while the editor does not exist in DOM, tinyMCE script thinks it's still out there. You can check it by placing a breakpoint on `tinymce.remove()` and running `tinymce.editors.length` - it will return a positive value even if the editor is not there. For some unknown reason the problem appears only in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
    try {
        tinymce.remove(tinymce.editors[0]);
    } catch (e) {
        // alert(e);
    }
}
```

Try the code above. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error is annoying. It has to do with a racing condition.
Try to put your remove command in a setTimeout-Block before you reinit the editor and it should work.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
    if (ed) ed.remove();
}, 1);
```

**Update**: Then try something different:

```
var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
if (ed) ed.remove();

setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery('#tinymce').tinymce({
    height: 250,
    width: 750,
    entity_encoding: "raw",
    encoding: "xml",
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    forced_root_block: 'div',
    statusbar: false,
    theme: 'modern',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: "mention " + plugins,
    toolbar1: toolbar1,
    toolbar2: toolbar2
   });
}, 1);
```

Comment: Hi Thariama, Thank you for your input, I have tried your solution , but if i put remove command in timeout then it stopped working on the first try as remove command is being executed after init command, hope you are getting me!!

Comment: then try something different, make sure to use the correct editor id

Comment: Hi Thariama, Yes the editor id was correct, I tried your updated solution also, but this issue is arising while executing remove command, I mean at the line where 'ed.remove()' is being executed while opening the tinymce second time.

Comment: what happens if you raise the timeout duration?

Comment: It doesn't matter , as the exception is being thrown where remove command is being executed. Hope you are getting me!!

Comment: i think the problem is that your editor ionstance is not shut down correctly no matterwhat. have a look here to see how this can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759111/tinymce-4-remove-or-destroy

Comment: tried this one already , unfortunately it is also of no help in case of mozilla

Comment: hmm, i am out of options then, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In my case all suggestions doesn't work.

I used this code to resolve my issue with Firefox and NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED:

```js
if( typeof window.tinymce != 'undefined' && $(window.tinymce.editors).length > 0 ){
  $(window.tinymce.editors).each(function(idx) {
    try {
    tinymce.remove(idx);
    } catch (e) {}
  });
}
```

Hope this will help to someone.