# How to have the JQuery version of tinyMCE open multiple text areas in popups when clicking on a table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

OK, so I'm trying to create a template that will be used for providing information for multiple scenarios in the same format. To do this, I have a table set up that will show the information, and when you click on one of the cells ('s specifically), it will place the inner HTML into a text area that comes up in a jQuery modal dialog box. This text area is then turned into a TinyMCE instance for editing (using Tiny MCE javascript version 4.3.2). However, with my current code, this only works the first time. After that, no matter what cell is clicked, I get a popup that shows as empty, though it has the proper HTML inside when I run inspect element.

I have seen similar things in previous questions, but one of them only wanted to use jQuery to have the popup work, which I've done, and the other was not using the jQuery version, and the solution code did not work with this version, but it seems that it simply closed out the instance when the dialog was closed so that it could be redone on the next text area. Also, I'm using a custom CSS for looks, but the jQuery Start scheme is the closest available scheme, if you want it to look pretty while you troubleshoot.

Edit: To clarify, I am not trying to open multiple runs simultaneously, they should open one at a time.

Code:

```
<head>
    <script src="assetts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assetts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {                
            $('td').click(function (event) {
                var currentId = this.id; 
                var currentHTML = this.innerHTML;
                alert(currentId); 
                $(function () { 
                    $("<div id=\"editmodal-diag\"></div>").dialog({
                        title: 'Edit',
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                var t = "#" + currentId; 
                                alert(t); 
                                $(this).dialog("close"); $("#editmodal-diag").remove(); 
                                tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, '#editmodal-diag-text'); 
                            },
                            Cancel: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close"); $("#editmodal-diag").remove(); 
                                tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, '#editmodal-diag-text'); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })
                $('#editmodal-diag').append("<textarea id=\"editmodal-diag-text\">" + currentHTML + "</textarea>"); 
                $('#editmodal-diag-text').empty; 
                $('#editmodal-diag-text').tinymce({ plugins: 'link' }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="75%>
        <tr>
            <th>Header text</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Information panel 1</td>
            <td>Information panel 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging, I found [TinyMCE 4 - remove() or destroy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759111/tinymce-4-remove-or-destroy), in which I found that the tinymce control needed to be removed with:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'editmodal-diag-text');
tinymce.remove();
```

to completely remove the current editor, before being reinitialized by:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'editmodal-diag-text');
$('#editmodal-diag-text').tinymce({ plugins: 'link'});
```

This only needed to be done after the first box came up. I used a Boolean variable to check this. Complete function:

```
var tinyRun = false;
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('td').click(function (event) {
            var currentId = this.id; 
            var currentHTML = this.innerHTML;
            alert(currentId); 
            $(function () { 
                $("<div id=\"editmodal-diag\"><textarea id=\"editmodal-diag-text\"></textarea></div>").dialog({
                    title: 'Edit',
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                            var t = "#" + currentId; 
                            alert(t); 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); $("#editmodal-diag").remove(); 
                            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'editmodal-diag-text');
                            tinymce.remove();
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close"); $("#editmodal-diag").remove(); 
                            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'editmodal-diag-text');
                            tinymce.remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#editmodal-diag-text').text(currentHTML);
                if (!tinyRun) {
                    $('#editmodal-diag-text').tinymce({ plugins: 'link' });
                    tinyRun = true;
                }
                else {
                    tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'editmodal-diag-text');
                    $('#editmodal-diag-text').tinymce({ plugins: 'link' });
                }
            }, 250);
        });
    }, 250);
}
```